# Wordpress WP_LIST_PAGES insert span

Tags: wordpress

I have this code:

```
if($post->post_parent)
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
else
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
if ($children) { ?>
<ul id="siderbar_menuchild">
<?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

The result is:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="page_link">page_name</a></li>
<li><a href="page_link">page_name</a></li>
etc...
</ul>
```

Now this is what I want to display:

```
$text1="text1"
$text2="text2"
$text3="text3"
etc...

<ul>
<li><a href="page_link">page_name<span>text1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="page_link">page_name<span>text2</span></a></li>
etc...
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

LE: Ok I put the following line:

```
$children = str_replace('</a>', '<span></span></a>', $children);
```

And now the tags placement is good.

But I still have to find a way how to put different text to each span.

LE2: I used jquery to insert text, didn't found any PHP method, I used the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".page-item-53 span").text("Your text here Your text here Your text here");
</script>
```

So I solved my problem, but if you have any other better way in doing this, you can post here your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `link_after` attribute for `wp_list_pages()` to achieve this.

```
if($post->post_parent)
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&link_after=<span>text </span>");
else
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&link_after=<span>text </span>");
if ($children) { 
?>
<ul id="siderbar_menuchild">
<?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

And for number, i use css `counter-increment`

```
<style>
body {
  counter-reset: section;           /* Set the section counter to 0 */
}
#siderbar_menuchild  li.page_item 
{
  counter-increment: section;
} 
#siderbar_menuchild li.page_item span:after { 
  content: counter(section); 
}
</style>
```

Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters

Comment: I don't want to write text1, text2 inside the span, I want to put custom text to each span.